# Overall code coverage showing zero after running test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Every now and then I encounter the following issue after I run my test classes, they all marked as completed and pass, however the class in the section Overall code coverage shows as 0 (some of them not all).

I need then to run the individual test class for that particular class, once this was complete the class in that section is updated

[image: Code coverage]

I have try changing the option of ticked and also unticked in Always run async, all the test have been also by clicking the button run all

[image: developer console run test]

I am wondering if there is anything else I can do, as it is quite frustrating to have to search individual test class to run in order to get a better overview of the code coverage in the org

Comment: Do you share your org with anyone? It's possible to delete all code coverage at once by going to the Apex Test Execution page and clearing the history.

Comment: is happening on both production and sandbox, and yeah I clear test history from view test history >> clear test data buton, and also deleted all records from "SELECT Id FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate"

Comment: Can you check Setup > Development > Apex Test Execution > Options, and see if "Store Only Aggregated Code Coverage" is selected?

Comment: @sfdcfox, at the moment all of the 3 options are unticked

Comment: Hmm. I just tested this in my dev org, it seems to be working fine. How big is your org, number of classes/code approximately.

Comment: @sfdcfox yeah i spretty bizard sometimes happens and sometimes doesnt, I dont think is that big a total of 106 test classes, and not many manage packages install only docusign and marketing cloud